# Autowired is not working for TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory in spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am writing a gateway for microservices using spring cloud gateway. I am trying to configure the gateway to forward the authentication token to downstream services.

**I am not able to autowire the TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory class.**

Below is my gateway's pom.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using spring cloud version 2020.0.3

And below is my configuration of routes,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class RouteConfig {
    @Autowired
    private TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory;
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
            .route("test",r->r.path("/test/**")
            .filters(f->f.filter(filterFactory.apply()).removeRequestHeader("Cookie")).uri("http://localhost:8082"))
            .build();
}
}
```

When i am trying to run the project, i am getting the below error,

```
Description:

Field filterFactory in com.package.apigateway.configuration.RouteConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory' in your configuration.
```

When i am using the the same class from '`org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.gateway.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory`' the package(which is deprecated), i am not getting the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spring Cloud Security was removed from spring cloud 2020.0. `TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory` is now part of spring-cloud-gateway itself.

Comment: I have spring-cloud-gateway dependency as well. But still i am getting this error.

Comment: Remove spring cloud starter security

Comment: That works!!.. Thank you so much.. May i know what would be the reason for it?